# clickhouse insert into multi line statement syntax error

Tags: clickhouse

I have this code

```
CREATE DATABASE hello;

CREATE TABLE hello.orders (order_id Int64, items Array(String)) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY order_id;

INSERT INTO hello.orders (order_id, items) 
VALUES (1, ['laptop', 'mouse', 'keyboard']),
       (2, ['book', 'pen', 'notebook']);
```

But it fails with this error:

> DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 2 ('2')

See fiddle https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/00d22ab7-6fbf-496f-a89b-e19d9bc605bc

One way to fix this is to put values from `INSERT` to one line. But why does it fail? And how to insert in multi line?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't like you linefeed or spacing for some reason. This worked fine (in your Fiddle):

```
CREATE DATABASE hello;
CREATE TABLE hello.orders (order_id Int64, items Array(String)) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY order_id;



INSERT INTO hello.orders (order_id, items) VALUES (1, ['laptop', 'mouse', 'keyboard']),(2, ['book', 'pen', 'notebook']);

SELECT * FROM hello.orders;
```